# SQL developer: Export schema script with data/index tablespace name?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently using SQL Developer with no complaint, now there is a question about how to export schema script with data/index tablespace name on it.

There is an option when right click table => Export => under "Export DLL" there is a check box for "Schema" but not for tablespace.

So how can we achieve massive script exporting with tablespace name all along?

Or, is there any other tool/command to handle the job?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Storage` option when exporting. To get DDL for a single object you can also use [`DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_metadata.html#dmgd) function but if you need to export whole schema with complex dependencies it is better to use specialized tools like SQL Developer / Toad / PL\SQL Developer, etc.